# Angular 2 reset form to initial data without having to set each formcontrol individually

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a formGroup which I open in edit mode and initialize with the proper data.
I also save this initial data in editForm.

After doing changes to it I want to reset all the changes to the initial values, something like:

```
this.formGroup.reset(this.staffToEdit);
```

But all this does is put blank in every field. The only workaround I found is to do something like

```
this.formGroup.reset({field1 : this.editForm.field1});
...
```

The thing is I need something more generic that resets all the fields to their initial value without having to go through each formControl.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so this was a weird interaction but I finally fixed it.

Initially I had my reset button inside the form:

```
   <form .. > 
   .....
    <div>
    <button id="resetButton"
            type="reset"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            (click)="resetFormData()"> Reset
    </button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

After I pulled the button out of the form, I just save my initial values after ngOnInit:

```
this._originalData = this.formGroup.value;
```

and after that when I want to reset I use

```
protected resetFormData() {
      this.formGroup.setValue(this._originalData);
  }
```

If you keep the button in the form, you cannot use it to update form control values!

Comment: I think your problem was that the button had the type 'reset', which causes the default HTML reset behaviour to occur, namely setting all inputs to their default value (blank or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

What I do is keep a reference of the initial values and just use a `patchValue()` call together with a `markAsPristine()` to set all form values back to what they initially were, and marking the entire form as pristine.

```
const initialFormValues {
  firstname: 'Joe',
  surname: 'Doe'
};

...

reset() {
  this.formGroup.patchValue(initialFormValues);
  this.formGroup.markAsPristine();
}
```

Or as I'm guessing it will look like in your case:

```
reset() {
  this.formGroup.patchValue(this.editForm.value);
  this.formGroup.markAsPristine();
}
```

Comment: This is what I hoped to avoid because I have several forms and wanted a generic way to do it without having to implement it in each form. But as far as I found seems to be the only way.

Comment: @Fofole I guess you can create a helper service with an observable event stream to handle reseting multiple forms, making it more general in your specific use case. As far as I know angular itself does not provide any more generic ways of doing it in multiple form cases. It is difficult to provide any more help without knowing more about how you are creating and managing the forms in your application, and how the form data is structured.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I found the problem with my code and posted it as an answer.